# Declaring a javascript array of infinite objects

Tags: javascript

How can I declare a JavaScript object which can hold infinite amount of values like given below? I am new to Javascript.

```
var activities = [
  {
    subject: "",
    genre :"",
    username: "",
    aboutuser: ""
  },
  {
    subject: "",
    genre :"",
    username: "",
    aboutuser: ""
  },
  {
    subject: "",
    genre :"",
    username: "",
    aboutuser: ""
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: You don't have to predeclare the size of any variable in javascript; just declare an empty array and you can `push` onto it as many times as you like.

Comment: Probably *arbitrary* rather than *infinite* - your clients only have so much RAM.

Comment: Arrays are a dynamically sized type in JS. Do you actually need Array storage, or do you just need a type that will continuously generate them in a loop? What's the actual usage here?

Comment: You can declare an empty array: `var arr = [];` then use a `for` loop and `push` as many object as you want: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { arr.push( { /* ... */ } ); }`. (this adds `10` objects).

Comment: Are you looking for something like "infinite lists" using lazy evaluation?

Comment: Have you run into some sort of problem with the code you have (as posted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
  let myArray = []

  myArray.push({
    subject: "",
    genre :"",
    username: "",
    aboutuser: ""
  })
```

Just define an empty array and push the object into it as many times you need.

Comment: no problem. Just mark the answer as correct for other people future reference. Happy Coding

Comment: thats still definite ;D Some other solution for this?